# After updating Blender to 2.90 UI looks weird. How can I fix that

Tags: interface, theme

Every button, slider, tab, checkbox looks cut. Does somebody know how to fix that?

I'm using Xubuntu 20.04

[image]

Comment: Please add the name of your GPU(s) (integrated and dedicated) to your question. It might be that they below the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender 2.90. Additionally you should check if update graphics drivers are available for your hardware.

Comment: This is an issue with the GPU, update the drivers using the proprietary drivers from the manufacturer (not open source ones)

Comment: [Some more tips](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) about how to ask good questions.

Comment: My GPU: Mobility Radeon HD 5470. And yes. I have some problem with that (not available CUDA/OpenCL/RTX features, and when I apply multiple materials to single object - I got artefacts in 3D Viewport and Eevee rendered viewport)

But I'm not sure, that the reason of current problem is open source drivers. Otherwise this issue appears on Blender 2.85 I believe
But I'll try to install proprietary GPU drivers and check.
Thank you

Comment: The [Radeon HD 5470](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_5000_series) is below the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender 2.8x and later. It has the TeraScale 2 micro-architecture, but [GCN first generation or later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#API_Overview) is required. Graphics glitches or even crashes can occur on unsupported hardware. You may still be able to run Blender, but it's not guaranteed to work.